# sshfs finding the password for the root user of a remote machine?

Tags: root, sshfs

I'm currently setting my laptop and raspberry pi to have a sshfs link between the two for quick file transfer.  I was able to log into the users of each machine using my password with no issue, so that allows me access to their directories.  However, I'm hoping to be able to mount the root of each machine to each other.  When I attempt to do this using

sshfs root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /path/to/mount/

It prompts me for the root users' passwords (for each machine).  However, the password which I use on each machine to access the root user is not working.  Is there a default password that root users tend to have when it comes to SSH?

Comment: Is root login via ssh enabled? Check this: `grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Is scp really so much more difficult than cp as to make this worth it?  What distribution are you using?  Some disable remote login as root, you may be running into that config issue.